# How to select mutual Tinder matching in SQL?

Tags: sql

Say theoritcally we have a table called matches (with some test data):

```
create table matches (
  user_id int,
  target_id int
);
INSERT INTO matches VALUES (1,2);
INSERT INTO matches VALUES (2,1);
INSERT INTO matches VALUES (3,5);
INSERT INTO matches VALUES (4,1);
INSERT INTO matches VALUES (1,4);
INSERT INTO matches VALUES (5,3);
INSERT INTO matches VALUES (5,4);
INSERT INTO matches VALUES (4,5);
INSERT INTO matches VALUES (1,3);
INSERT INTO matches VALUES (1,5);
INSERT INTO matches VALUES (6,1);
INSERT INTO matches VALUES (6,2);
INSERT INTO matches VALUES (6,3);
INSERT INTO matches VALUES (6,4);
INSERT INTO matches VALUES (6,5);
INSERT INTO matches VALUES (6,6); // me_irl
```

So for this test data set, we should expect the following mutual Tinder match:

```
1,2
4,1
5,3
5,4
```

How would I select this in SQL?  Here is what I got, which works but select duplicates:

```
select A.user_id A, B.user_id B from
matches as A
inner join 
matches as B
on A.user_id = B.target_id
where A.user_id = B.target_id
and B.user_id = A.target_id
```

This is what the SQL query returns:

```
A   B
1   2
1   4
2   1
3   5
4   1
4   5
5   3
5   4
```

Comment: If you add a condition in which `A < B` you should eliminate the duplicates (i.e. 1,4 and 4,1). Additionally, you are aliasing A and B twice (once for the selected values and once for the source tables).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter out the duplicates by adding "a.user_id < b.user_id".

Like this:

```
select A.user_id A, B.user_id B from
matches as A
inner join 
matches as B
on A.user_id = B.target_id
where A.user_id = B.target_id
and B.user_id = A.target_id
and a.user_id < b.user_id
```

Comment: I like this solution better, it's easier to understand than using case

Answer (score 1):

```
 select distinct case when A.user_id<B.user_id then A.user_id else B.user_id end as colum1,  case when A.user_id<B.user_id then B.user_id else A.user_id end as colum2 from
    matches as A
    inner join 
    matches as B
    on A.user_id = B.target_id
    where A.user_id = B.target_id
    and B.user_id = A.target_id
```

Try this. I haven't checked. Hope it works